# Flexbox today - how can I use it

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm really confused about flexbox. Is this good idea to use it for modern browsers? I'v heard that I should not use it for whole page layout but I dont know why. And where is good idea to use it and where not?

Comment: One problem with it is the fact that Internet Explorer doesn't do it very well.  It does do a lot of things you can't do with traditional CSS, though.  If IE isn't a requirement, I would suggest using it.  View this page as a reference for its compatibility:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Hi Karolina, your question is quite broad. It also invites opinion-based answers. Both qualities are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Your question is likely to be downvoted and closed.

Comment: That said, I'm building my websites using flex layout. The better option would be [CSS Grid Layout](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/), but browser support is still very weak, so we'll need to wait a few more years. Bottom line: Unless you need IE 8 or 9 support, flex can work. I've written more about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no if you need Internet Explorer support.
For Edge and other browsers i'd recommend using it ... See [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) for supported browsers.

If you do need older browser support, rather go with some css grid framework or include lower IE specific styles using conditional includes or take a modernizr-like approach.

Plenty of crossbrowser and browser-specific solutions to your problem ... you have too choose, can't say more since this is a very broad question which can trigger various types of responses depending on people's experience and personal taste.